# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2020-08-16 17:33:21.690' from column 18 to TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, mysql

i am getting the below exception. But few rows able to get values from result set and able to map to java pojo. could someone help me in debugging this stuff ?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2020-08-16 17:33:21.690' from column 18 to TIMESTAMP.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1336)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:575)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6686)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6005)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:4961)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:5011)
        at com.freeware.gridtag.DBGrid.getColumnValue(DBGrid.java:712)
        at com.freeware.gridtag.DBGrid.drawGridWithOutColumns(DBGrid.java:2550)
        at com.freeware.gridtag.DBGrid.doEndTag(DBGrid.java:600)
        at org.apache.jsp.mainReport_jsp._jspService(mainReport_jsp.java:725)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
  
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 0000_15975991715696�8SMPPMTTX2020-08-16 17:33:21.647
TRAFFIC-SPLIT2020-08-16 19:13:21.690Venu-Traffic-Split-On-net2020-08-16 17:52:41.877311110
             HANDSET_ACK2020-08-16 17:33:21.6902020-08-16 17:33:21.6902020-08-16 17:52:40.000lid:1915976003605490 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:2008161752 done date:2008161752 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:3310
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.getInt(StringUtils.java:756)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1114)
        ... 54 more
```

any help was appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Except prior to MySQL 5.6.4 where it was stored without the microseconds.

I believe @liuguoshun 's gh-ost example is:

mysqld is 5.5. I don't know what version gh-ost is.
mysqld has the settings time_zone='+08:00' and sql_mode=''. Zero dates are allowed.
gh-ost is running on the master host, connecting to the master mysqld.
The example table has a timestamp field create_time of default 0/'0000-00-00...'. Because of the default setting and no ON UPDATE, this value isn't automatically modified when the row is updated.
The example table only has one row, with create_time= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
mysqlslap is updating that one row with update test11 set counter=counter+1 where id=1, so create_time isn't being explicitly updated.
gh-ost is adding a new column to the table, with no change specified to create_time: add column name varchar(1)
(Assumption) gh-ost, when parsing the master's binary log, is seeing the row event for the UPDATE and converting the after-image create_time '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (however it's represented in 5.5 row events, I don't know, 0?) to '1970-01-01 08:00:00 +0800 CST' when it's applying the update to the new _test11_gho table.

create_time should just be copied from test11 to _test11_gho without modification, in this example, but it is. I'm hoping this is enough information for @shlomi-noach to know what to ask for from @liuguoshun next.

Answer (score 0):

It'a a bug in mysql-connector, at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast.

Try to use a higher version, or add "useFastDateParsing = false" to JDBC connection.